# How to call static member when its in class (this is normal class)

Tags: c#

In an interview I face this problem, how can I call static member here:

```
 public  class PermenatEmployee
 {
      public static string/void sayGoodBye()
      {
          return "GoodBye";
      }
 }

 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     var gsgsg = PermenatEmployee.sayGoodBye;
 }
```

Here I have choice of using `string` or `void` in the method.

Comment: `string/void`? That's not valid c#

Comment: Exactly how you have it right now, with `()` :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Access a static method in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521420/how-to-access-a-static-method-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the string/void.

Code will look like this:

```
public class PermenatEmployee
{
    public static string sayGoodBye()
    {
        return "GoodBye";
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var gsgsg = PermenatEmployee.sayGoodBye();
    }
}
```

If you really wanted to return a string and a void you could use return type of void on the method then use an out parameter of string like this:

```
 public class PermenatEmployee
{
    public static void SayGoodBye(out string action)
    {
        action = "GoodBye";

    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PermenatEmployee.SayGoodBye(out var action);

        Console.WriteLine(action);
    }
}
```

Comment: if i have void then how can i

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite confused by the syntax here: `string/void`, if it's to indicate that it could be either, then to make a static function call you need to invoke the function with `()`, i.e.:

```
var gsgsg = PermenatEmployee.sayGoodBye()
```

That being said, you can't assign the return value of a `void` to a `var`.

You also can't have a method outside of class scope, so your example will fail to compile.

Answer (score 0):

In your class PermenatEmployee:

```
public class PermenatEmployee
{
    public static string sayGoodBye()
    {
        return "GoodBye";
    }
}
```

In your program class:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(PermenatEmployee.sayGoodBye());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can just call it by it's name,

```
 public  class PermenatEmployee
 {
  public static string/void sayGoodBye()
  {
      return "GoodBye";
  }
 }
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
 var gsgsg = sayGoodBye(); // your answer

}
```